# How to write Odoo-14 Record Rules

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Good day,
I have written a record rule just as below

```
domain=['|',('type', '!=', 'private'),('is_prescription', '=', True)])
```

Am using it in a variable just as below

```
`product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', ondelete="cascade", string='Product', required=True, domain=['|',('type', '!=', 'private'),('is_prescription', '=', True)])`
```

To break it all down

The `('|',('type', '!=', 'private'),('type', '=', False))` helps me to bypass the default rule for multi company products.

And the record rule `('is_prescription', '=', True)` helps me to get a specific product.

But the rule `domain=['|','|',('type', '!=', 'private'),('type', '=', False),('is_prescription', '=', True)]` is not helping to get a specific product that is a prescription, what it does it get all the products.

What i want to achieve is to bypass the default rule then get a product that is Prescription no matter what company the product belongs too and the user is in.

Please help me, I am new to Odoo

Answer (score 0):

Put your prescription rule with "**AND-condition**" with other rule instead of "**OR-condition**"

```
domain=[('is_prescription', '=', True),'|',('type', '!=', 'private'),('type', '=', False)]
```

Comment: domain=[('is_prescription', '=', True),'|',('type', '!=', 'private'),('type', '=', False)]
Not working

Comment: can you add an screen shot of all the record rule for model "product.product" or "product.template"

Comment: Thank you but i have decided to build a new model